# Ruby SE Realtime: A library for watching the SE Realtime WebSocket

Tags: library, ruby, realtime

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

Documentation can be found in the GitHub repo: https://github.com/izwick-schachter/se-realtime

### About

This is the library you need when you don't want to have to poll the API every minute to get new questions. You can just watch the realtime socket! It'll be awesome! Do it!

#### License

This project is released under the MIT License. Any contributions are welcome via pull requests. Feature requests can be made via issues or in chat.

#### Download

Although the library is [published on rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/se-realtime), the version there will frequently be outdated. To keep up to date please [install from GitHub](https://gitlab.com/izwick-schachter/se-realtime). The master branch should never be broken, so `bundle update` regularly. This is easy if you're using the bundler gem, you can just add the following line to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'se-realtime', git: 'https://gitlab.com/izwick-schachter/se-realtime`, branch: 'master'
```

#### Platform

This library should work anywhere ruby will run. That means definitely macOS/Linux, and possibly windows.

### Contact

If you are getting started, I know that documentation is poor, so please ping me in chat. I can be found in either of the two testing rooms for this library, [Under the Bed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63561/under-the-bed) and [The Closet](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63296/the-closet). Ping me whenever, I should respond within 48 hours.

In addition, if you have any feature requests, ping me in chat. I would be more than happy to try to add functions you need or to help you better use SE Realtime.

### Dependencies

- MRI Ruby 2.5.0